# Rails returns HTML, even with `application/json` set and `.json` added to resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Attempting to render JSON via Jbuilder when an XHR request is sent to Rails, and HTML when a normal request is sent. But every request still returns HTML.

**Without JBuilder**

1. `PostController` has a show action. It renders html and json.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(1)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @post}
  end
```

2. Request `locahost:3000/posts/1.json`
3. It renders JSON fine.

---

**With JBuilder**

1. Remove the respond_to block.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(1)
  # Remove the respond_to block
end
```

2. Add Jbuilder view:
   `app/views/posts/show.json.jbuilder`

**It looks like this:**

```
json.slug @post.slug
json.title @post.title
json.body @post.body
```

3. Request `locahost:3000/posts/1.json`
4. Rails Console output: `Processing by PostsController#show as JSON`
5. And yet, It renders `posts/show.erb`

**Why?**

- From JBuilder's examples, adding `.json` is enough to trigger Rails to render the Jbuilder view. But it doesn't happen.
- Also using `Postman`, changing the `Accept` and `Content-Type` to `application/json`. This also renders `posts/show.erb`, and returns HTML to the browser.

---

**Adding back a respond_to**

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(1)
  respond_to :json, :html
end
```

1. Request `locahost:3000/posts/1.json`
2. Rails Console output: `Processing by PostsController#show as JSON`
3. Renders `posts/show.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Why is your view named show.erb? Can you try changing it to show.html.erb